# Animation on TabItem creation?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Is it possible to animate a TabItem when it's created ?
I would like to create an animation which will slide the TabItem from the bottom of my window to the TabControl itself and add some fade in effect too :)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes.  You can associate an animation with the `Loaded` routed event as shown below.

```
<TabItem>
    <TabItem.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <!-- animations go here -->
                    </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </TabItem.Triggers>
</TabItem>
```

You can then put any animation you want in the `Storyboard` to give the desired effect.